# Resizable page with min-width and position absolute?

Tags: position, absolute, resizable, css

I'm working on a resizable page with a sidemenu to the right, and it almost works as supposed on this simple example:

http://pastehtml.com/view/1do8cy9.html

The problem though is that position auto and min-width dont react as expected. If you drag the browserwindow smaller than 500px (as the min-width is set to), the red sidemenu continues over the green content..

How do I make the sidebar stop when it reaches the min-width, fx 500px?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The absolute positioned div should be inside the min width div which should have position relative

**Edit, better explanation:**

For the sidebar: add `top: 0` to the red sidebar and place it inside the `min-width` container.

For the container: replace the `margin-right` property with `padding-right` and add `position:relative`

Comment: If i do like you suggested, it overlaps the green content with text instead of "resizing it".. The min-width works now though :S Like here: http://pastehtml.com/view/1doa3jv.html

Comment: add margin-right:220px; to the div with the text; and if u want to move the green background to it.

Comment: actually this fixed my problem, i'm really interested to know why it is like this? is it a bug? i don't think so because all the browsers behaved like each other in my case. the relative div should be realtive to absolute div, but putting an absolute div inside of a relative div is not what i had in mind!

Answer (score -1):

I have a fix !

It's weird though:

```
body{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    min-width:1300px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```